# Firebase database structure and query format options

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, geofire

Basically, my app has posts based on location that can be upvoted/downvoted.
I need to construct a query that returns the top 15 upvoted posts that lie in a specified region, and were made in the last 24 hours. Coming from an sql background, I am finding this unnecessarily difficult to do with the JSON format and firebase's built in query by order and filtering options. I realize i will most likely have to a lot of client side filtering, so I am asking what the JSON structure and query format would be to minimize client side filtering. So far this is what my JSON format looks like:

```
  "posts" : {

    "-KPFIsDbf3WUljWvBwi-" : {

      "latitude" : 33.64114800203589,
      "longitude" : -116.4236003651668,
      "time" : 1.47129994542173E12,
      "uid" : "wjXpBBJMBVPvRVG48fFkerAw6TD3",
      "upvotes" : 0
},
```

I tried using Geofire, but unfortunately that seems to only have the ability to query by region, and since I want to query by region and time posted (among other things), using Geofire will not scale well.

Comment: Do you know what your regions will be beforehand? Or are they decided by user location?

Comment: The query regions could be anything

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I would do in a similar setup, using a combination of GeoFire and Firebase queries:

Step 1 (saving): When saving a post, save it to the database first, using a random ID. Then, grab that ID, create a GeoFire location, and set your post ID as the location key.

Step 2 (querying): This will be a 2 step query

Step 2a: Get all GeoFire locations within specified region. Now, you can grab the keys of all locations from the snapshots and and attach a single data event handler on each.

Step 2b: Maintain a sorted array of post objects by number of upvotes. In the snapshot for single event listener, first check the timestamp to see if it is within the last 24 hours. Next, if the array has a count of less than 15, add your post in sorted position (using an appropriate parsing method). If it already has 15, you'll need to see if the minimum lowest element in the array has more upvotes. If it does not, you'll need to find a place in the array to replace. After you are done parsing through every snapshot from Geofire, you will have your array of posts from the last 24 hours, sorted by upvotes.

Comment: Sounds like this would work. The only thing i'm worried about is performance as the post list grows. Since I'm storing every post forever, inevitably there will be worse and worse performance as clients have to filter through more and more posts. What would you estimate approximately would be the total amount of posts this method could handle before running into problems? (let's assume worst case where the user has to query every single post). Thanks

Comment: Well, capturing a snapshot if you already have the ID is fairly quick. I would say it would start causing performance problems once you get near 1,000 posts, though, considering there is also the sorted array portion of this. I'm going to take a look at what GeoFire queries are doing under the hood, in an attempt to combine everything into one query. I'll get back to you soon.

Comment: So, after taking a closer look, it does not seem feasible to add a third constraint to this query. Geofire is already doing a lot to do latitude and longitude in the same query. You will have to implement the rest on client side.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I was thinking It might even be better to just query all posts in the last 24 hours and do the longitude/latitude filtering on the client side

Comment: Yes, that's a decision you'll have to make. It depends on if you think there will be more posts in the last 24 hours or more posts total in the specified region.